# C# проверка Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (400) Недопустимый запрос

Tags: c#, webclient

В коде c# есть такая строка:

```
string[] url = new WebClient().DownloadString(domen).Split('\n');
```

которая получает массив с урла domen, если в качестве domen подсунуть домен с ошибкой в написании: к примеру site.ru//, то программа падает с ошибкой: System.Net.WebException: "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (400) Недопустимый запрос."
Подскажите, как добавить проверку на корректность domen или игнорирование данной ошибки?

Comment: [try-catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

Comment: 1. `WebClient` - является устаревшим компонентом в языке C#, об этом сказано в документации! Стоит заменить на `HttpClient`. 2. Для ссылок в C# есть специальный компонент, зовется `Uri`, стоит использовать его для хранения и валидации, например вы можете сделать так `if (Uri.TryCreate("...", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out var uri)) { //отправка если валидна }`.